# iOS: How to handle multiple buttons created dynamically with one iBAction?

Tags: ios, uibutton, xcode6, ibaction

I have created radio and check box buttons programmatically according to my web service response, where number of buttons varies.

Following is the code to create those buttons:

```
for(int j = 0; j < nintOptionCount; j++)
    {
        UILabel * lblOption =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(50, yLabel, 250, 21)];
        //lblOption.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        lblOption.text = [arrmOptionName objectAtIndex:j];
        lblOption.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        lblOption.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
        [viewDetail addSubview:lblOption];            


        intOptionId = [[arrmOptionId objectAtIndex:j] intValue];

        if (intEventChoice == 1)
        {
            btnRadio = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, yLabel, 22, 22)];
            [btnRadio addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [btnRadio setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_radio.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btnRadio setTag:intOptionId];
            [btnRadio setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"radio%d%d",intOptionId,intParamId] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [viewDetail addSubview:btnRadio];
        }
        else
        {
            btnCheckBox = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, yLabel, 22, 22)];
            [btnCheckBox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btnCheckBox addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxButtonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [btnCheckBox setTag:intOptionId];
            [btnCheckBox setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"check%d,%d",intOptionId,intParamId] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [viewDetail addSubview:btnCheckBox];
        }

        yLabel = yLabel+ 21+10;
    }
```

So, my question is how to handle action on those buttons where buttons are created programmatically? and how to handle selection and deselection of buttons as those buttons are work like radio buttons and check box buttons.
in case of radio button if i select one then other needs to be deselect and in case of check box, selection and deselection of check box needs to be managed.

I have tried with setting tag to buttons but its not working properly as i expect.

Please provide me some solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: One option is to make an array containing all buttons , give them tag. Now when one one button is selected , loop through array and deselect all other buttons for radio button case.

Comment: @Bhagyashreemahajan Assign tag to every button. and from tag you will easily find which one you have clicked.

Comment: @Bhumit Are u able to provide some sample code for your solution so i will get clear idea about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare your button inside your for loop. so each time loop  run a new instance of button will generate.

Create array to save buttons.

```
NSMuttableDictionary *btnRadioDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
NSMuttableDictionary *btnCheckBoxDictionary= [NSMutableDictionary new];
```

Set tag for each button inside loop

```
for(int j = 0; j < nintOptionCount; j++)
{
UIButton *btnRadio;
UIButton *btnCheckBox;
// your other code


  btnRadio.tag = j; 
  btnCheckBox.tag = j;

// save buttons to an array
[btnRadioDictionary setValue:btnRadio forKey:j];
[btnCheckBoxDictionary setValue:btnCheckBox forKey:j];
}
```

And identify the button clicked using tag in the IBAction

```
 -(IBAction) radioButtonPress:(id)sender 
 {
   // Write code Deselect all button here
   for(NSString *key in btnRadioDictionary)
   {
    UIButton *button =[btnRadioDictionary objectForKey:key];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_radio.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   }
   // Select required button

    UIButton *button =[btnRadioDictionary objectForKey:[sender tag]];
    [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:SELECTED_IMAGE_FOR_RADIO_BUTTON] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   //Write separate action for each button if required.

   switch ([sender tag]) {
    case 0:

        break;
    case 1:

        break;
    case 2:

        break;
        /*
        .................
        */
    default:
        break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i can not use switch case because my number of buttons varies according to web service response. So i don't know how many switch cases should i write.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a data structure, either from arrays and dictionaries or custom classes, to allow you to represent your groups of buttons, their types and their current selection state. This data structure can link directly to the buttons so that when an update is made you can iterate the buttons in the group to update them.

Using `tag` is a cheat way of getting info about the selected button, but it is cheap and convenient. It's also hard to subclass buttons. One alternative is to use [associated objects](http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/) to give each button a weak reference to it's section of the data structure, so you can go straight there following selection.